# Refatoração para Spring Data retornando List<Object[]>

Tags: java, spring, spring-jpa

Me deparei com um projeto onde tenho diversos métodos no `Repository` deste tipo:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT "
        + "  i.uf, "
        + "  i.cidade "
        + "FROM Imovel AS i "
        + "WHERE i.ativo = 'Sim' AND "
        + "      EXISTS (SELECT 1 "
        + "              FROM ImovelFoto AS f "
        + "              WHERE f.codigoImovel = i.codigo)"
        + "GROUP BY i.uf, i.cidade", nativeQuery = true)    
List<Object[]> findUFCidade();
```

Espero trocar para um objeto como este:

```
public class LocalizacaoAgrupadaDTO {

    private String uf;
    private String cidade;

    // Getters e Setters omitidos
}
```

[Nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35714286/5230740) no SOen, a solução passa por trocar a query para JPQL.

No entanto, essa troca adiciona uma complexidade extra, devido a sintaxe diferente e até aos mapeamentos das entidades, sendo que este select é agrupamento, sem relação direta com as entidades.

**Qual a melhor maneira de fazer esta refatoração com Spring Data JPA?**

Devo sempre priorizar o uso de JPQL ou é possível com nativeQuery?

Comment: Você quer transformar um `List<Object[]>` em `List<LocalizacaoAgrupadaDTO>`? Fazer "na mão" ficaria muito ruim?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Hoje é feito na mão, numa classe service.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que a melhor maneira de você trabalhar para essa situação seja com pojos e não com objects.

Respondendo sua pergunta se você deve priorizar o uso de JPQL ou utilizar NativeQuery a resposta é:

**DEPENDE**

A **vantagem** do JPQL é que se vc mudar de banco de dados no decorrer do projeto, está alteração tende a ser muito menos problemátiva se comparada com o native query. Visto que algumas expressões variam de banco pra banco.

A **desvantagem** do JPQL é questão de performance. Uma native query tende a ser mais performática, visto que não é necessário realizar um "build" para converter a expressão JPQL em um sql para determinado banco.

Para situações como está eu **SEMPRE** opto para criação de Pojos. Abaixo um exemplo utilizando JPA com hibernate:

```
public List<Perfil> listAll() {
    return manager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM perfil", Perfil.class).getResultList();
}
```

**Entidade / Pojo Perfil:**

```
@Entity(name= "perfil")
public class Perfil extends BaseEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_perfil")
    private Long idPerfil;

    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "dt_criacao")
    private Date dtCriacao;

    @Column(name = "dt_edicao")
    private Date dtEdicao;
```

Comment: Também concordo com o Karan, A complexidade aumenta mais por outro lado ganha em performance..